# I can succesfully show asset logo but i still get the error: Unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a use case where i have to load the asset image based on the value of the key `logo_image` from a json file.

So i have this json with key `logo_image` and value `image1.png`:

```
{
  "logo_image" : "image1.png"
}
```

There is an image inisde the assets folder like this: `assets/image1.png`

I have a class called `GetAssets()` with a method called `getAssetItems()` which loads the json file and another method called `getLogo` which i will use as blueprint in the view to specify which key item i want to view:

```
class GetAssets {

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getAssetItems() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/items.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;



  Future getLogo(String key) async {
    var assets = await GetAssets().getAssetItems();
    return 'assets/' + assets[key];
  }
}
```

I have a field called `logo` and i have method called `setAssets()` to load the logo and set the state of the logo with `setState()` and i use `initState()` to initialize `setAssets()`. I have a `Scaffold()` which i use to view the asset logo with the field `logo`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowLogo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowLogoState createState() => _ShowLogoState();
}

class _ShowLogoState extends State<ShowLogo> {
  late String logo = "";
  setAssets() async {
    final logoFromAsset = await GetAssets().getLogo("logo_image");

    setState(() {
      logo = logoFromAsset;
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    setAssets();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Image.asset(logo),);
  }
}
```

I am able to show the logo on the screen of my phone, but i still get the error: `Unable to load asset:` What is the cause of this? How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of Json asset asynchronous method call.

When the widget executing then `build(BuildContext context)` method try to build the widget immediately after the `initState (setAssets)` method call.

For `setAssets` method's asynchronous call, `build(BuildContext context)` method already executed before setting `logo = logoFromAsset` inside `setAssets` method and the first time `logo` variable remains with empty string which is not a valid asset path, thats why `Image.asset(logo)` can not load the asset/image and throw an error.

But after few moment when your `setAssets` asynchronous method call executed and called `setState` this time the widget is rebuild with the non-empty/valid asset path and the logo is showing.

Try to set an default image/icon and I think this will resolve your issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowLogo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowLogoState createState() => _ShowLogoState();
}

class _ShowLogoState extends State<ShowLogo> {
  late String logo = "";
  setAssets() async {
    final logoFromAsset = await GetAssets().getLogo("logo_image");

    setState(() {
      logo = logoFromAsset;
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    setAssets();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: logo != "" ? Image.asset(logo) : const Icon(Icons.image)
    );
  }
}
```